# JQuery Week Calendar Issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, jquery-plugins

In my project, I am using the [JQuery week calendar plugin](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/). I call a php script to retrieve the data and show it in the calandar. Following is my code

```
var id = 3; 
     var type = "c";
     var dataString = "id=" + id + "&t=" + type;
     $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"actions/client.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

In PHP:

```
function getCalendarData($appoint_id){
                $retunArray = array();
                $sql = "SELECT id, appoint_start, appoint_end, total FROM account WHERE id = '".$appoint_id."'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                    $retunArray[] == $row;  
                }
                echo json_encode($retunArray);
            }
```

It gives me a 500 error. Has anyone used it before with PHP. Can anybody help me to get the data from the db and show? any alternative good way than this

Thanks

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? json_encode doesnt work PHP <5.2

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/using-json-encode-and-json-decode-in-php4/

Comment: json_encode is working, my php version is 5.3+ and my rest of the form contents are sent and retrieve through json, so its not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Check the response in your browser. If you use G. Chrome press F12, click in Network tab and in the bottom click on XHR. Click in the response to expand the information

Maybe you are gzipping the JSON data, 
are you using any php framework?

Comment: no any framework. this is what I'm getting

`POST http://localhost/pet_care/actions/client.php
 
500 Internal Server Error
  248ms`

Comment: That is the response, but you should also be able to see the data being sent to the server. Either the data being sent is incorrect, or your code on the server dealing with it is failing.

Comment: Hi now I could get the data as json source, but the showing part is not working, I just gave the json out put file as this:

`data: "json_data.php"`

Comment: If you solved the error500 update your code so we can see where it fails now